What kinds of subordinate clauses can a wh phrase be extracted from? What kinds not?
The following sentence has a subordinate clause:

Spock asked Kirk [whether Scotty fixed the warp drive].

I want to derive a Wh-question from the sentence, so that the wh-word or interrogative pronoun (e.g. who) refers to a word inside the subordinate clause (e.g. Scotty).  Is the following question grammatical?

Who did Spock ask Kirk whether fixed the warp drive?

That is to say, can a wh-word move from inside a subordinate clause to the front of a question?  Is it dependent on the type of the subordinate clause?

I’m voting to close this question because it uses an unknown abbreviation. What is "a wh phrase"? Not everyone knows all the abbreviations, so they should not be used. The question also needs editing as I suspect it still does not make sense even if "wh" is written in full.

They can be extacted from the first, third, eighth and eleventh kinds.

The question title is missing a preposition.

@TimR What are "the first, third, eighth and eleventh kinds"? What are the others?

I find it hard to imagine a competent Anglophone deliberately framing such a question, but if they did, I think it would have to be Who did Spock ask Kirk whether they had fixed the warp drive? Or maybe About whom did Spock ask Kirk whether they had fixed the warp drive? Answer, Scotty, obviously, so you'd have thought Spock would already know that,

While I would have voted to close this as unclear, I find it surprising that anyone voted to close as "proofreading." I feel like that vtc reason has been abused a lot lately. This is in no way a proofreading question. IMO it could be rehabilitated by stating the real question more clearly, and by finding or inventing a less ridiculous example (i.e., for a question "Can I do X," there should be some reason for supposing that you can do X, not just fantasy).

@AndyBonner: I didn't vtc anyway, but it seems to me it is either a proofreading question or a "pointlessly vexatious" question. I personally can't think of a "less ridiculous" real-world question involving Who did X ask Y...? where all 3 of the highlighted elements refer to different people like that. But I believe it's either "ungrammatical" or at the very least "totally unidiomatic" not to reprise the referent of who with a pronoun (they, he, she - obviously it can't be an actual proper noun, since that's what the asker is trying to find out).

@ishtar thanks. If I want to generate a wh question sentence, and the wh phrase is from a subordinate clause, when is it grammatical and when is it not?

The issue I have with this question is that it is not based on an actual problem.  You have created a complex sentence, apparently for the purpose of a grammar puzzle, rather than being faced with an actual problem in communication.  To solve the communication problem you would not use a simple wh-question, but some interrogative dialogue.  THe key here is dialogue not monologue.  You need to be aware of the other person in the question,  the person who will answer the question.

So what is the real problem of communication?  I assume you aren't really having a conversation about Spock!

What is real what is not? Why can't my question be treated as it is

whether is more or less synonymous with if.  Clauses it introduces are converted to questions using "Did".    Did Scotty fix the warp drive?

OP can phrase the question in this manner::
"Who, according to Spock's question to Kirk, fixed the warp drive?"
This question is more idiomatic and still refers to Scotty as the one who fixed the warp drive.

The sentence "Who did Spock ask Kirk whether fixed the warp drive?" is ungrammatical due to constraints in English syntax that prevent the extraction of a wh-word from within certain types of subordinate clauses.
Wh-Island Constraint
The issue here involves what's known as the "wh-island constraint." In English, when a subordinate clause is introduced by a wh-word (such as "whether"), it creates a syntactic environment from which a wh-word (like "who") cannot be extracted to the front of a question. This constraint is why the sentence you provided sounds ungrammatical.
Wh-Word Movement
In English questions, a wh-word typically moves to the front of the sentence to form a question. A wh-island is created by an embedded sentence that is introduced by a wh-word, creating a dependent clause. The resulting sentence, if you try to move the wh-word, ends up sounding ungrammatical. This is closely related to 'adjunct islands'.
To form a grammatical question that involves asking about the subject within the subordinate clause, you need to avoid extracting the wh-word from that subordinate clause.
In summary, the original question sounds ungrammatical as it tries to move a wh-word from a wh-island to the top of the structure, and this behavior is indeed dependent on the type of subordinate clause involved.
